# Ruby reassignment after chained methods (sort_by, reverse etc)

Tags: ruby, syntax

Just learning Ruby for the first time and playing around with it to learn how to do <s>functional programming with it</s> not mutate the object before I explicit want to mutate it (using `!`).

```
text = "foo bar baz baz baz Foo FOO foo"
# Splitting the sentence into an array of words
words = text.downcase.split(" ") 
# Hash to store the frequencies of each word
frequencies = Hash.new(0) 
# Count the instances of a word one by one
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
# Sort it by the most frequent words
frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count}.reverse!
# Print out the histogram
frequencies.each { |word, count| puts "#{word} #{count}"}
```

prints out the following

```
foo 4
bar 1
baz 3
```

The expected results would be

```
foo 4
baz 3
bar 1
```

I know that it can be solved by this

```
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count}.reverse!
```

**But I do like the simple `!` reassignment syntax in ruby and are wondering if I can avoid this `frequencies =` ?**

---

Doing `frequencies.sort_by! { |word, count| count}.reverse!` throws an `undefined method` error.

<s>I also find the working solution a bit counter-intuitive since it resolves first</s>

```
frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count}
```

then assign it to `frequencies =` and then it calls the next method `.reverse!`

## EDIT

I now think understand how to read the working solution. The

`frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count}`

returns a new Hash which then is reversed by `reverse`.
The `!` does nothing since it "reassigns" the new (sorted and reversed) hash which has no variable assignment.

Then the whole thing is assigned to `frequencies`

Comment: I doubt I follow how one who “wants to learn how to do functional programming with it” would _ever_ prefer mutating methods. In my professional career, there were zero cases when I used method mutating the receiver (those with bangs.)

Comment: “since it resolves first [...] then assign it to `frequencies =` and then it calls the next method”—this is plain wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? You wrote that you want to do functional programming, but `reverse!` is the *exact opposite* of functional programming.

Comment: As mentioned: I'm new at Ruby (please bear with me). I do see the conflict in fun.prog. and use of `!` in my question. I think it was because I expected `sort_by` and `reverse` to non-mutating methods

Comment: I think `frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| -1 * count}` would eliminate the need for `.reverse`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Is there a list over Ruby hash mutating and non-mutating methods?

Comment: There is a convention in Ruby: mutating method names end with a bang.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin and it's not possible to "bang" `sort_by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're just doing imperative programming, because I see mainly a list of statements.
I suggest you to wrap the logic in a function so that you can clearly define what are the inputs and the output you're dealing with:

```
def word_frequencies(text)
  words = text.downcase.split(" ") 
  frequencies = Hash.new(0) 
  words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
  frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count}.reverse
end
```

This way you are clearly stating that:

- text is the only input
- you won't mutate the input
- you won't generate side effects. Each time you invoke the function, given the same input, the output will always be the same and the only output will be the value returned by the function.

Once you clearly define the function's boundaries, there's no shame in performing assignments.

There's point where you need to generate side effects, such as printing something to the screen:

```
frequencies = word_frequencies("foo bar baz baz baz Foo FOO foo")
frequencies.each { |word, count| puts "#{word} #{count}"}
```

Finally, if you want to experiment with a completely chained program, you can do so with [`Object#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
"foo bar baz baz baz Foo FOO foo".then do |text|
  text.downcase.split(" ")
end.then do |words|
  words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, memo|
    memo[word] += 1
  end
end.then do |frequencies|
  frequencies.
    sort_by { |word, count| count}.
    reverse
end.each do |word, count|
  puts "#{word} #{count}"
end

# foo 4
# baz 3
# bar 1
```

Pick your poison. :-)

Comment: I like the concept of defining a method that is non-mutating.

Comment: `"foo bar baz baz baz Foo FOO foo".downcase.split.each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }.sort_by(&:last).map { |e| e.join(" → ") } .map(&method(:puts))` :)

Comment: thx for the oneliner @AlekseiMatiushkin ;-) (I had to drop a `.reverse` in to make it work though.